# C# replace text after a keyword in a file

Tags: c#, file

How can i change a text that comes after a keyword?

My file is like below;

[DbServer]=localhost 
[DbUser]=user 
[DbPassword]=pass 
[DbName]=testDb

For ex. how can i find user that comes after [DbUser]= and change it in c#?

Comment: hint-- `IndexOf` or `string.Contains()` or `string.SubString()` function or a mixture of 2 of the 3. also what have you tried on your own..? this is not that difficult, also read up on `string.Replact()` function. good luck sounds like you have some reading to do .. also if this is reading from an `.INI File` start reading up on `Configuration.Manager` and how to use it

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...

string[] lines = new string[] {
  "[DbServer]=localhost", 
  "[DbUser]=user", 
  "[DbPassword]=pass", 
  "[DbName]=testDb"};

foreach (string line in lines) {
    string user = "<none>";
    var m = Regex.Match(line, @"^\s*\[DbUser\]\s*=\s*(\S+)\s*");
    if (m.Success) {
        user = m.Groups[1].Value;
        line = Regex.Replace(line, user, "Joe");
        #replaced User with Joe and reassigned it to line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void replaceWordInFile(string fileName, string keyWord, string newWord) //Keyword sonrasındaki stringi verilen string ile değiştirir
    {
        StreamReader reading = File.OpenText(fileName);
        string pattern = @"\w+=([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)";
        string str;

        while ((str = reading.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (str.Contains(keyWord))
            {
                Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
                Match match = regex.Match(str);

                if (match.Success)
                {
                    testLabel.Text = match.Groups[1].Value;
                }
            }
        }
        reading.Close();
    }
```

Comment: i can find the requested word after keyword by using pattern. Now i need to change the value with new value in a text file.